# Scroll only sidebar in flex content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a **wrapper** which contains two *divs*. I want the **content** to be fixed, so not scrollable. The sidebar contains a list of usernames, so it has a big content through **y** scroll.

I have tried many stuff, like adding *display: auto;* but it keeps scrolling the whole page.

Here's how my HTML file looks like.

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header"></div>

        <div class="sidebar-filter"></div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components"></ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content">
        CONTENT
    </div>

</div>
```

And here's the CSS file.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Although it looks very easy, but I am stuck in this problem for 2 days.

Comment: You are not explaining the behavior you want very clearly -- things like "y scroll", and "fixed" is all very abstract, I'll pen up an answer but it would be nice if you edited your question and explained for instance, how the side bar is supposed to behave -- how is the relationship between its height and the height of its parent and other ancestor elements? Same for content element.

Comment: The sidebar will contain a ul list of usernames (like over 600) and it looks ugly, if you scroll the whole browser (including the content) instead of only the sidebar.

Comment: This doesn't work in Safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use   [`overflow-y: scroll;`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) and set fixed `height`(for example: `height: 120px;`) to `#sidebar`

**EDIT!**

to you comment

> I want the sidebar to be in full height,

use `height:100vh`

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
        overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 100vh;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar  -->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header"></div>

        <div class="sidebar-filter"></div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li>user name</li>
        <li>user name</li>
        <li>user name</li>
        <li>user name</li>
        <li>user name</li>
        <li>user name</li>
        <li>user name</li>
        <li>user name</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content">
        CONTENT
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I mean, but I want the sidebar to be in full height, how I do it? Tried using stretched flex, but doesn't work, thanks for your support.

Comment: it still doesn't fit the browser

Comment: so  try `height:100vh`

Comment: happy to help :)